# wordpress - javascript validation hook for admin

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am trying to build in some custom post validation behaviour for wordpress admin forms and I would like to know if there is a way I can add a listener to some code, somewhere, to catch validation results. I am primarily interested in doing this with javascript as my problem is UI based.

Thanks.